# When is the Optimal weighting matrix in GMM singular?

Tags: regression, autoregressive, method-of-moments, generalized-moments, matrix-inverse

currently I am trying to estimate a simple linear regression:
\begin{equation} 
y_t = X \beta + \varepsilon_t,
\end{equation}
where I try to find 4 coefficients and one specific predictor is an autoregressive predictor: $y_{t-1}$. OLS will yield biased results so I am attempting to use GMM with the following moment conditions:
\begin{equation} 
E(y_{t-2}\varepsilon_t) = 0 \\
E(y_{t-3}\varepsilon_t) = 0 \\
E(y_{t-4}\varepsilon_t) = 0 \\
E(y_{t-5}\varepsilon_t) = 0 \\
E(y_{t-6}\varepsilon_t) = 0 \\
\end{equation}

After implementing GMM in MATLAB, I get the following warning: "Matrix is close to singular or badly scaled. Results may be inaccurate. RCOND =  1.080661e-21.".
Moreover, this warning is quite correct as my estimated GMM coefficients are of the magnitude e+150...

I know that the optimal weighting matrix $W$ is the following:
\begin{equation} 
W = S^{-1} = (E(g(x_t, \beta)g(x_t, \beta)'))^ {-1},
\end{equation}
where $g$ are my moment conditions.

Why is my Weighting matrix singular? and how do I prevent it? What advice can you give me to solve the endogeneity problem for estimating my regression?

Comment: Do you think GMM will yield unbiased results? I would doubt that.

Comment: @RichardHardy I do not think it will yield unbiased results, GMM is generally biased I know. But is GMM a better way to estimate a regression including an Autoregressive explanatory variable compared to OLS? if not, are there better estimation methods?

Comment: I do not know, but I do not remember hearing that GMM would be preferable to OLS in such cases, so perhaps it is not. But I am not sure. Also, see [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/182592/) and the comments by Glen_b.